# How to replace all spaces between a <p> and </p> tag

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am going through about 5000 records and needing to replace all spaces between a `<p> </p>` tag with `&nbsp;`

Would this work?

I thought this would work with a SET replace()

```
SELECT *
FROM FMS.[AuditItem] ai
WHERE ai.[NotificationMessage] LIKE '%<p>% %</p>%'
```

But I still have no way to select only the spaces between the paragraph tags. Right? Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: how about using substring to get the <p> </p> tag and replace.. i never tried before but just a thought.

Comment: I agree with AJP above but would probably wind up doing this in code where I have RegEx available.

Comment: Use an HTML or XML (whichever is appropriate) parser to parse HTML or XML. There will always be valid HTML/XML that will be misinterpreted even if you use regexes, and `LIKE` cannot do anything a regex cannot. String matching will say the space in "`<p>a</p> <p>b</p>`" is between `<p>` and `</p>`. If your response to that is that you don't have strings like that, please clarify what you do have.

Comment: Is this column valid XML?  Sample data would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take a look

the string can contain some of these patterns

```
 sometext<p>sometext</p>sometext
 sometext<p>sometext</p>
 <p>sometext</p>sometext
 <p>sometext</p>
 sometext</p>
 <p>sometext
 sometext
```

if you want reduce risk so should be considered previous patterns
so, well it is the example

```
  declare @mem table(id int identity(1,1), NotificationMessage varchar(80))

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select 'that is some text initial<p> one two three four  </p> asdf asdf asdf'

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select '<p> one two three four  </p> asdf asdf asdf'

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select 'that is some text initial<p> one two three four  </p>'

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select '<p> one two three four  </p>'

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select 'one two three four  </p>'

  insert into @mem(NotificationMessage)
  select 'one two three four'


  select
  NotificationMessage,
  case 
  when CHARINDEX('<P>',NotificationMessage) > 1  then SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,1,CHARINDEX('<P>',NotificationMessage)-1)
  else ''
  end as section1,

  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,                                                                                                    
                        case when CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) > 0 then
                                    CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) + 3
              else 1
                        end,                                                                                                    
                        case when CHARINDEX('</P>', NotificationMessage) > 0  then
                                    CHARINDEX('</P>' , NotificationMessage)
              else LEN(NotificationMessage) 
                        end 
                        -
                        case when CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) > 0 and CHARINDEX('</P>', NotificationMessage) > 0  then
                                    CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) + 3
              else 1 end) , ' '
   ,'&nbsp;') as section2,

  case 
  when CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage) > 1 then
   case when len(NotificationMessage) > (CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage) + 4)  then SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage)+4,  len(NotificationMessage) - CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage)+4 )
   else ''
   end
  else ''
  end as section3,

  case 
  when CHARINDEX('<P>',NotificationMessage) > 1  then SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,1,CHARINDEX('<P>',NotificationMessage)-1)
  else ''
  end 
  +
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,                                                                                                    
                        case when CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) > 0 then
                                    CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) + 3
              else 1
                        end,                                                                                                    
                        case when CHARINDEX('</P>', NotificationMessage) > 0  then
                                    CHARINDEX('</P>' , NotificationMessage)
              else LEN(NotificationMessage) 
                        end 
                        -
                        case when CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) > 0 and CHARINDEX('</P>', NotificationMessage) > 0  then
                                    CHARINDEX('<P>' , NotificationMessage) + 3
              else 1 end) , ' '
   ,'&nbsp;') 
  +
  case 
  when CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage) > 1 then
   case when len(NotificationMessage) > (CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage) + 4)  then SUBSTRING(NotificationMessage,CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage)+4,  len(NotificationMessage) - CHARINDEX('</P>',NotificationMessage)+4 )
   else ''
   end
  else ''
  end as newstring
  from @mem
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one set of p tags in the column then this is only going to grab the first, the rest will get removed. If that's ok then this should do the trick

```
UPDATE FMS.[AuditItem]
SET    [NotificationMessage] = REPLACE(SUBSTRING([NotificationMessage]
                                                  ,CHARINDEX('<P>' , [NotificationMessage]) + 3
                                                  ,CHARINDEX('</P>', [NotificationMessage]) - CHARINDEX('<P>', [NotificationMessage]) - 3)
                                       , ' '
                                       ,'&nbsp;')
WHERE  [NotificationMessage] LIKE '%<P>%' AND [NotificationMessage] LIKE '%</P>%'
```